# Coal Funds & ETFs With Non-US Exposure

Tags: investing

I invest in green energy, but the universe is not going to magically flip a switch and get off coal this second, nor should every country do this since it may be too costly for their growth.  The United States seems heck-bent on bankrupting all of its coal companies, making US coal a bad choice for investors ([source for global importance of coal](http://www.iea.org/aboutus/faqs/coal/)).

Are there any coal Mutual Funds/ETFs without (or very little) US company exposure?  Ex - if you look at `KOL`, 15% of its exposure to coal is US, which will be worth nothing in a few years.

Comment: If US coal companies are in fact going to be worth nothing, you'd think sophisticated investors would have already considered this and priced their shares appropriately. But if you think you know better than the market and want to speculate (something I'd strongly recommend against), then ETFs are not the product for you.